# Image not uploading to ImageView in Galexy Note 3

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm working on a application. I have a upload button in that application. When i click on upload button mobile gallery opens then i select image and upload it to ImageView. My application is working in few mobile devices but when i try it on Samsung Galexy Note3 The application not responds while uploading image to imageview. Please help me.

Code of upload button:

```
upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE1);
        }
    });
```

Code on onActivityResult:

```
switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            this.path1 = picturePath;
            // iv1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            try {
                iv1.setImageBitmap(decodeBitmap(selectedImage,
                        EyeMatch.this));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            iv1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            break;

        }
```

Code of Bitmap decodeBitmap :

```
public static Bitmap decodeBitmap(Uri selectedImage, Context context)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver()
            .openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;

    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            break;
        }
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver()
            .openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
}
```